# How to get work from ethermine.org?

Tags: mining-pools, stratum

I could not find any tools or software that only supports getting work (or in other terms, getting the block data and target) from Ethermine pools. The [ethermine.org's website](https://www.ethermine.org/start) provides the host address, port number for mining and also provide windows/linux software for receiving the data via proxy and then mining it. I'm only interested in just the proxy part and receiving the data and target. Is there any python library or executable files that only gets the job from ethermine.org?

[image]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you wish to just get the latest block's data and possibly even mine yourself on top of it? If yes, why not just run a full node yourself. Or use a node provider such as Alchemy or Infura

Comment: I have updated my question with a diagram to better explain what I am trying to do

Comment: @tweety It seems that ethermine uses stratum protocol to get the mining work. If you subscribe to the stratum server like a mining client it should send the work details.